# How to send a video in chunks in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I am using Html 5 video in my ASP.NET 4.0 application. But the problem is that when I use a big video file, the video will be never played until the download complete. How to send this video in chunks in ASP.NET. Any example will be appreciated?

Comment: Maybe look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687677/how-to-stream-video-content-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: Or if you want to support Range Requests look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783106/playing-a-video-file-from-a-sql-server-blob-via-ashx-handler-using-html5-video-t/12783572#12783572